# print pdf image in Jupyter Notebook in Chrome

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to print out pdf image in Jupter notebook. I would normally use this command:

```py
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame("image.pdf", width=600, height=300)
```

However, this only works in Mozilla Firefox and not Chrome. I get a greyed out window instead. Is there any way I could display it in Chrome too?

Thanks

Comment: This looks [very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997580/jupyter-notebook-hyperlink-to-locally-stored-pdf-docs-stopped-working-in-chrome)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunatetly it still isn't working. This is the code I'm using.
```python 
from IPython.core.display import HTML
def pdf(url):
    return HTML('<embed src="%s" type="application/pdf" width="100%%" height="600px" />' % url)
pdf('images/con1.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried the above code and it was the same. I looked it up and found the following workaround posted.

`from IPython.display import display_pdf
with open('image.pdf', "rb") as f:
    display_pdf(f.read(),raw=True)`

[qiita.com by Japanese](https://qiita.com/Gomesu39/items/6e0898c9128e721d68e3)

Comment: When I run this script I get a hyperlink [View PDF] to a blank page.

Comment: Could it be an environmental problem? I ran it in a `jupyter lab` environment. The site information is posted in the `jupyter notebook` environment.
My environment is `ipython 7.13.0`

Comment: Getting same issue here, just a `[View PDF]` link

Comment: Same for me - a link and black page